# How to do this su + sudo in one command?

Tags: iptables, sudo, password, su

My son (not sudoer) is logged-in, and from *his* terminal, I sometimes want to `iptables` to remove the internet blocking (which will be back again after reboot ;)).

```
son$ su dad
<enter password>
dad$ sudo iptables -D OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT
<re-enter password>
```

**Is there a way to do this in one line instead, and possibly enter the password only once?**

I tried things like `su dad -c "sudo iptables -D OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT"` (but it was unsuccessful with `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`).

(Maybe with a .sh but this wouldn't solve the problem of two times entering the password?)

Comment: Is there a root password on this system?

Comment: You could make your son sudoer and not give him the password. I don't think that would be less secure than the current approach since If the dad pw is known it is possible to just su dad. Then you can just `sudo iptables` from your son's account.

Comment: @Max1 I tried to make him sudoer, but then `sudo anycommandhere` worked with *his* login password of *his* account! How to make him sudoer, but such that `sudo ...` works with *another password* than his account password?

Comment: @Basj your totally right. Didn't keep that in mind.

Comment: @roaima Your idea gave me a simple solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @roaima's comment, I just created a password for root (disabled by default with Ubuntu): `sudo passwd root`, and then I could just use this simple method:

```
su -c "iptables -D OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT"
<enter password only once>
```

Comment: Exactly. Another option is to tweak `sudo` to require the target account password rather than accept the originator's own password.

Comment: Oh good idea too @roaima. How to do this with sudo?

Answer (score 2):

With this `expect` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

log_user 0
spawn /bin/su - dad
expect "*: "
stty -echo
send_user "Password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send_user "\n"
stty echo
send "$expect_out(1,string)\r"
send "sudo iptables -D OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner son -j REJECT; echo done\r"
expect "*: "
send "$expect_out(1,string)\r"
expect "done\n"
```

See `man 1 expect` for details. The lines between `stty -echo` and `stty echo` are responsible for reading a password. It's possible to include a password in the script itself, but you probably don't want this. The password is read once and provided twice (`send "$expect_out(1,string)\r"`).

The script is dumb and does not care if the provided password works. Improve if needed.